# Use .tflite with iOS and GPU

Tags: ios, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu, quantization

I have created a new tflite model based on **MobilenetV2**. It works well without quantization using CPU on iOS. I should say that TensorFlow team did a great job, many thanks.

Unfortunately there is a problem with latency. I use iPhone5s to test my model, so I have the following results for CPU:

1. 500ms for MobilenetV2 with 224*224 input image.
2. 250-300ms for MobilenetV2 with 160*160 input image.

I used the following pod 'TensorFlowLite', '~> 1.13.1'

It's not enough, so I have read TF documentation related to optimization (post trainig quantization). I suppose I need to use Float16 or UInt8 quantization and GPU Delegate (see https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization).
I used **Tensorflow v2.1.0** to train and quantize my models.

1. **Float16 quantization of weights** (I used MobilenetV2 model after Float16 quantization)

https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_segmentation/ios

- pod 'TensorFlowLiteSwift', '0.0.1-nightly'

No errors, but model doesn’t work

- pod 'TensorFlowLiteSwift', '2.1.0'

2020-05-01 21:36:13.578369+0300 TFL Segmentation[6367:330410] Initialized TensorFlow Lite runtime.
2020-05-01 21:36:20.877393+0300 TFL Segmentation[6367:330397] Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Caused GPU Hang Error (IOAF code 3)

2. **Full integer quantization** of weights and activations

pod ‘TensorFlowLiteGpuExperimental’

Code sample: https://github.com/makeml-app/MakeML-Nails/tree/master/Segmentation%20Nails

I used a MobilenetV2 model after uint8 quantization.

```
GpuDelegateOptions options;
    options.allow_precision_loss = true;
    options.wait_type = GpuDelegateOptions::WaitType::kActive;

    //delegate = NewGpuDelegate(nullptr);
    delegate = NewGpuDelegate(&options);

    if (interpreter->ModifyGraphWithDelegate(delegate) != kTfLiteOk)
```

Segmentation Live[6411:331887] [DYMTLInitPlatform] platform initialization successful
Loaded model 1resolved reporterDidn't find op for builtin opcode 'PAD' version '2'

Is it possible to use MObilenetV2 quantized model on IOS somehow? Hopefully I did some mistake :) and it's possible.

Best regards,
Dmitriy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for outdated documentation - the GPU delegate should be included in the `TensorFlowLiteSwift` 2.1.0. However, looks like you're using C API, so depending on `TensorFlowLiteC` would be sufficient.

MobileNetV2 do work with TFLite runtime in iOS, and if I recall correctly it doesn't have PAD op. Can you attach your model file? With the information provided it's a bit hard to see what's causing the error. As a sanity check, you can get quant/non-quant version of MobileNetV2 from here: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/hosted_models

For int8 quantized model - afaik GPU delegate only works for FP32 and (possibly) FP16 inputs.

Answer (score 1):

This is a link to GITHUB issue with answers: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39101